# Angularjs Directive - refreshing or reloading with new data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two angularjs directives like below

```
<div class="well well-sm">
    <datepickcalendar processchange="getSummaryForGivenMonth(sD,eD)"></datepickcalendar>
    <barpiechart datavar="Summary"></barpiechart>
</div>
```

I display a bar and pie chart (barpiechart directive) and on top corner show a date picker (datepickcalender directive).
On page load, i show current month's data as charts (from controller, i populate 'Summary' and barpiechart's link function draw the chart.)

Now, when i select a date range using the date picker, controller populates 'Summary' with new values but the barpiechart is not refreshed.
After searching in google, i found out that link() function is called only once. So barpiechart is drawn only once with current month's data.

Again after googling for some days, i found a working solution for refreshing, that involves 
a. $scope.apply() in the controller function after populating 'Summary'
b. $scope.$watch in the link function of barpiechart directive

Controller

```
function getSummaryForGivenMonth(sD, eD) {
        $scope.Summary = [
           ...
        ];
        $scope.$apply();
    }
```

Directive

```
app.directive('barpiechart', function () {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.scope = {
        values: "=datavar",
    };
    directive.link = function ($scope, element, attributes) {
        $scope.$watch("values", function (newValue, oldValue) {
            //draw chart using values and append to element[0]
        });
    };
    return directive;
});
```

Question:
I am new to AngularJS and i dont know if this is ok way to do it.

I have two more charts in the same page like the same way. Should i be calling $scope.apply every time i change the directive's variables?

Is there any disadvantage of calling $scope.apply() manually (multiple times)?

If my approach is incorrect or inefficient, please suggest other ways.

Comment: Gonna to need to see more code

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. You don't need scope.apply each time, the directive should see it automatically, there's no disadvantage, you might run into an error when $apply is already in progress. To counter that, you can wrap the contents of the function in a $timeout which will apply automatically. Not sure why you are using apply, since again, angular will run apply automatically when changes happen. Unless you're using jQuery with Angular, then asynchronous functions would require an apply.